# Deixar em branco resultados repetidos de Join em tabelas 1 para N

Tags: sql, firebird

Desejo obter um resultado de um relacionamento **1 - N**, onde: para cada linha da tabela da esquerda, sejam acrescentadas novas linhas para a tabela da direita. Isso é possivel? Ou senão, seria possível ocultar os dados repetidos da Tabela_1? Com **Inner Join** "normal", aparecem os dados, porem, repete-se os valores da tabela da esquerda. Não sei também se usar **JOIN** é a melhor opção.

**TABELA_1**

```
ID___|_DESCRICAO_|_VALOR
1    | DEBITO    | 1000
2    | DEBITO    | 2000
3    | DEBITO    | 3000
```

**TABELA_2**

```
ID___|ID_TABELA_1|_DESCRICAO_|_VALOR
1    |1          | HAVER     | 500
2    |1          | HAVER     | 5000
3    |2          | HAVER     | 1000
4    |2          | HAVER     | 800
5    |3          | HAVER     | 1500
6    |3          | HAVER     | 500
```

**QUERY UTILIZADA:**

```
SELECT
 A.ID,
 A.DESCRICAO,
 A.VALOR,
 B.ID AS ID_T2,
 B.DESCRICAO AS DESC_T2,
 B.VALOR AS VLR_T2

 FROM
 TABELA_1 AS A INNER JOIN TABELA_2 AS B
 ON A.ID = B.ID_TABELA_1
```

**RESULTADO OBTIDO:**

```
ID___|_DESCRICAO_|_VALOR_|_ID_T1___|_DESC_T2___|VLR_T2___
1    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 1       | HAVER     | 500     
1    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 1       | HAVER     | 5000
2    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 2       | HAVER     | 1000     
2    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 2       | HAVER     | 800     
3    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 3       | HAVER     | 1500     
3    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 3       | HAVER     | 500
```

**RESULTADO DESEJADO:**

```
ID___|_DESCRICAO_|_VALOR_|_ID_T1___|_DESC_T2___|VLR_T2___
1    | DEBITO    | 1000  | 1       | HAVER     | 500     
     |           |       | 1       | HAVER     | 5000
2    | DEBITO    | 2000  | 2       | HAVER     | 1000     
     |           |       | 2       | HAVER     | 800     
3    | DEBITO    | 3000  | 3       | HAVER     | 1500     
     |           |       | 3       | HAVER     | 500
```

Ou seja, para cada "debito" na TABELA_1, preciso ver todos os haver(pagtos) da tabela 2, sem que se repita a informação da tabela 1.

[image: RASCUNHO]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Pelo que entendi , não , ou não de forma simples , esta "duplicidade" se resolve na camada de aplicação , mas já vi aqui no SOPT uma solução trabalhosa para SQL via "window functions"

Comment: @Motta, nesse caso, na camada de aplicação, tentarei então "editar" o DataSet gerado pela consulta, criando um novo DataSet com os dados repetidos "em branco".

Comment: Eu confesso não ter entendido o problema , para o caso de existir nas duas tabelas ou só em uma. Não seria o caso de partir da tabela2 e fazer um OUTER JOIN na tabela1 ?

Comment: @Motta, vou tentar sua sugestão.

Comment: @Motta, editei a pergunta, acredito que desta vez, conseguí explicar com mais clareza. ;-)